# Flutter: Dropdown slider from Appbar

Tags: flutter, slider, dropdown, appbar

I would really like to be able to have a dropdownbutton on my appbar that then shows a slider underneath it when you tap it. The dropdownbutton could show the value of the slider. I would like the slider to be vertical as well. Any ideas on how I could do this?